# UI not updated after $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I have the following angular.js controller.

```
function WorkSpacesController($scope, $http, notifications) {
  $scope.Workspaces = [];
  $scope.Query = "";
  $http.get("api/Workspaces/GetAllWorkspaces/").then(function(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          $scope.Workspaces.push(response.data[i]);
          notifications.showSuccess("Added new Item");
      }
  },
  function(data) {
      notifications.showError("Could not load workspaces");
  });
}
```

The `notifications.showSuccess` &  `notifications.showError` method displays a notification on the scree. using this script : https://github.com/alexbeletsky/ng-notifications-bar.

What is weird is that the `showSuccess` method actually works and displays the notification while the `showError` does not work and displays nothing. I debugged the code the everything looks fine the message is added to the messages array and no error is received. I also tried calling `showError` instead of `showSuccess` to verify that its not a bug and it works.

Any thoughts as to why the UI is not updated when calling `showError`?

Comment: For the `showError()` related message show up, your HTTP request should result in an error - does it? How are you forcing it to cause an error?

Comment: @callmekatootie I simply change the url to a non existing one.

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint and checked that it reaches that method, temporary replace to an alert or console.log and check what happens).

Comment: @Braulio Yes I have. And I also debugged into the showError method and it follows the same flow as the showSucees, with no errors. Console.Log also displays messages in the browser console.

Comment: Did you get any error on the dev output console? If isolated in a plunkr works (you can try to hit a github or flickr public rest api) it should be something related with your app

Comment: no errors. after fiddeling with it I noticed that the first call to showXXX does not work... only the second one. weird. If I write it twice then it works and I see only one message. seems to be a bug in my/component implementation...

Comment: Sounds like your problem is with the notifications service.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is probably somewhere inside your notifications service, because the following example is working properly.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('WorkspacesController', function($scope, $http, notifications, $templateCache) {
  $scope.Workspaces = [];
  $scope.Query = "";

  //for the purposes of this example, put a url into the http cache so we can load it without an actual http request
  //try a successful request
  $http.get('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css').then(function(response) {
      //for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      //$scope.Workspaces.push(response.data[i]);
      notifications.showSuccess("Added new Item (for good request)");
      //}
    },
    function(data) {
      notifications.showError("Could not load workspaces (for good request)");

    });

  //try a failed request
  $http.get('url_that_does_not_exist').then(function(response) {
      //for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      //$scope.Workspaces.push(response.data[i]);
      notifications.showSuccess("Added new Item (for bad request)");
      //}
    },
    function(data) {
      notifications.showError("Could not load workspaces (for bad request)");
    });

}).service('notifications', function() {

  return {
    showSuccess: function(message) {
      alert('Success: ' + message);
    },
    showError: function(message) {
      alert('Error: ' + message);
    }
  };
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="WorkspacesController as vm">

</body>

</html>
```